# How to check if XMLHttpRequest's send() supports File

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Safari's XMLHttpRequest's send() method supports a File argument. Firefox does not (yet).

How can I check if this is supported? In Firefox, it will just behave as if an empty string was passed.

I'm trying to avoid doing browser version detection.

Edit: FF 3.6 does seem to support it, but the question is still relevant for older versions or other browsers.

Comment: firefox <= 3.5 support send file in this way: xhr.sendAsBinary(file.files[0].getAsBinary()); where file.files[0].getAsBinary() is the input file point

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that if the File object can be created, than send supports it. In Gecko (firefox,) that will be true (File and the send's File compatibility were both released in 1.9 according to MDC)

Comment: in other words, `if (typeof File === "object") { … }`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

**EDIT**

This solution won't work as the File isn't passed as an additional argument, as pointed out by rnicholson.

Comment: I don't understand how this would help. (new window.XMLHttpRequest).send.length would return 1 in both browsers, would they not?

Comment: Indeed, my fault. I just assumed 'File' would be an additional argument. Should I delete the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you are probably looking for:

```
const XMLHttpFactories = [
  function () { return new XDomainRequest(); },
  function () { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
  function () { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); },
  function () { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP"); },
  function () { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); },
];

var xhr = null;

for (var i = 0; i < XMLHttpFactories.length; i++) {
  try { xhr = XMLHttpFactories[i](); break; } catch (exception) { continue; }
}

if (!(xhr && ('upload' in xhr) && ('onprogress' in xhr.upload))) {
  alert("Sorry, your browser is not supported.");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could plain old browser sniffing not help? [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) could possibly be enough?

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid doing browser version detection." Besides, which test in jQuery.support tests for this.